# Query on getting product that will expire in next 10 days from firestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a collection that has expiry date stored in cloud Firestore. I want to fetch all the products that will get expired in next 10 days. I  want to notify this to the user. Please help.

```
Products(collection)---(docId)---(name)Product1--expireDate(Timestamp)--
                    --(docId)----   (name)Product2---expiryDate(Timestamp).
```

Not sure if this is correct

```
Firebase.firestore().collection("product").where('expiryDate' == new Date()+10)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to show any code you've written that isn't working the way you expect.  It would also be helpful if you show actual data instead of just a document hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create proper date to compare:

```
let date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 10);
```

Than you can create a query:

```
Firebase.firestore().collection("Products").where("expiryDate","<",date);
```

How to use `where` method is [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#where).